# Postgres disconnect when running query inside spawned process?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a function that spawns a process, which performs a query like so:

```
  def trigger_schedule(u = %User{}) do
    spawn(fn ->
      (Repo.preload(p, :tasks)).tasks
      |> Enum.map(fn ts -> trigger_schedule(ts) end)
    end)
    u
  end
```

This code is triggered by certain actions, and is simply meant to run in the background. However, when I run tests, I start seeing this:

```
00:37:33.324 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.789.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) owner #PID<0.1531.0> exited while client #PID<0.1533.0> is still running with: shutdown
```

Is performing queries inside of a spaned function not proper, or is there a way to get around this error? I assume this has something to do with the PG connection pool...

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because of the Ecto 2.0 Connection Ownership feature. The problem is that the process owning the connection (that is the test process) exits before the process running the query (in `spawn`).

I guess you're running your tests asynchronously. If you're using Phoenix and `ModelCase` you probably have `:ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(YourApp.Repo)`. The simplest solution is not to use `async: true` in your tests.

You could also try to manually allow another process to access the db with `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.allow(Repo, self(), process_pid)` but you have to know the pid of the process, which I'm not sure is possible since your `trigger_schedule` function returns the user, not the pid.

Comment: It seems that not using `async: true` doesn't solve the problem either? This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335635/ecto-2-0-sql-sandbox-error-on-tests seems to mention that "Using {:shared, self()} does not fix it". I even explicitly wrote `async: false` but it didn't help.