# Presence not picking up user leave events?

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to perform some actions when the user leaves a channel (in most cases where they close the tab voluntarily, but there may also be a connection loss/timeout etc.)

According to posts like https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-presence-run-some-code-when-user-leaves-the-channel/17739 and [How to detect if a user left a Phoenix channel due to a network disconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934029/how-to-detect-if-a-user-left-a-phoenix-channel-due-to-a-network-disconnect), intercepting the `"presence_diff"` event from `Presence` seems to be a foolproof way to go, as it should also covers the cases where the connection terminates abnormally.

Strangely, the `presence_diff` event seems to only be triggered when I track the user via `Presence.track`, but not when the user leaves.

Meanwhile, adding a `terminate(reason, socket)` callback in my channel correctly catches the leave event.

I wonder what could be wrong in my configuration. Or did I not understand the use of Presence correctly?

Example code:

```
def join("participant:" <> participant_id, _payload, socket) do
  if socket.assigns.participant_id == participant_id do
    send(self(), :after_participant_join)
    {:ok, socket}
  else
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end
end

def handle_info(:after_participant_join, socket) do
  experiment_id = socket.assigns.experiment_id

  Presence.track(socket, experiment_id, %{
    # keys to track
  })

  # Broadcast something
  # broadcast(socket, ...)

  {:noreply, socket}
end

intercept(["presence_diff"])

def handle_out("presence_diff", payload, socket) do
  # Only gets triggered at Presence.track, but not when the connection is closed.
  IO.puts("presence_diff triggered, payload is #{inspect(payload)}")

  leaves = payload.leaves

  for {experiment_id, meta} <- leaves do
    IO.puts("Leave information: #{meta}")

    # Do stuffs
    end
end

# This works, however.
def terminate(reason, socket) do
  IO.puts("terminated. #{inspect(reason)}")

  # Do stuffs.
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I know what happened: Each `"participant:" <> participant_id` topic is, as its name suggests, only subscribed to by one participant. Therefore, when that participant quits, the process also dies and nobody is able to act on the `presence_diff` message.

A separate process is still needed. One can call `MyApp.Endpoint.subscribe` from that process to subscribe to the `"participant:" <> participant_id` topic and act on the `presence_diff` messages.

Or one can set up an external monitor. See [How to detect if a user left a Phoenix channel due to a network disconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934029/how-to-detect-if-a-user-left-a-phoenix-channel-due-to-a-network-disconnect)